# How to License a software that uses google drive API

Tags: open-source-definition, google-code

I recently developed a software which currently uses google drive API for some functionalities, i am looking forward to release the software to the public for free. however i am not sure on which kind of license strategy i should go for. then also i would like to make my source code read only and available on repositories like Github in which fork and pull request on my source code will be requiring permission.
Could you please provide me more information and advice on how i can go through this.

-- note that i am using the Google drive REST API, this is a c# application therefore i downloaded the google drive client api DLL file into my application.

the application basically sends and receive data which is stored on google drive of a user's account.

please let me know if any further information is required

Comment: Some observations: - Acceptance of pull requests is always at your discretion; - When you publicly publish code on GitHub, you automatically grant other users the right to fork your code (but no other copyright-related permissions); - When you publicly publish code, many people will (possibly incorrectly) assume that the code is open-source and can be modified by them.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thank you for the information... that means i can still my application closed source (but freeware) even with the fact that i am using google drive api which i believe is a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License. –

Comment: I can't tell if you can keep your application closed source without more information. Are you directly accessing the Google Drive REST api, or are you using a client library provided by Google? If so, which client library are you using? The CC-BY license is not recommended for software and I didn't see any indication that Google is doing so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question does not contain enough information to provide an objective answer. You need to state your intention about what is actually relevant for choosing the right license: how you think about people creating and distributing modified versions of your software.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau  i have modified the question to contain more information

Comment: @Philipp the question have been modified

Comment: @TobiOwolawi I'm sorry, but when you don't want anyone to create derivative works without your permission, then you aren't looking for an [open source](https://opensource.org/osd) license. That means your question is off-topic here.

Comment: For the question about Google's API, you need to consult the license of the actual code that you copied into your project. E.g. if you copied from https://github.com/gsuitedevs/dotnet-samples/tree/master/drive/DriveQuickstart then that one says it is the Apache license, so you need to abide by those terms to use it. It is also possible to implement the access to a REST API using your own original code; in that case you can license that code however you choose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Google Drive client library for the .NET platform is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license. This license does not limit in any way what license you can apply to your own code.

Given your licensing conditions, especially that the source code would be read-only and forking is restricted, open source licenses are just plain out. That also means that it is off-topic for this site to recommend a particular license.

In short, the Google Drive library license allows you to keep your project closed-source, but we can't recommend a particular license.

Comment: Making a project read only on a hosting site like GitHub is independent of the license. If the license says you may modify and redistribute it, then you may do that (e.g. by downloading it and uploading it to another Web site), even if the hosting platform implements some kind of "read-only" mode or disables the "fork" button or something like that.

Comment: @Brandin: The way I understood the 'read-only' requirement is that the OP does not want to allow others to modify the code.